# Route params not recognized by Vue Router 3

Tags: vue.js, parameters, vue-router

For some reason Vue Router (3.6.5) does not recognize a URL with a param in the URL in one of my Vue apps. The setup of my Router index-file is like this:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)
let routes = [];
routes = routes.concat(publicRoutes, authenticatedRoutes, catchAllRoutes);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (store.getters.loggedIn) {
            next()
        } else {
            next('/401');
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

publicRoutes contains the following path:

```
path: '/',
        component: Frontpage,
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {

            console.log('to', to);
            next();
        }
```

What I would expect, based on all the documentation and other stuff I read, when I navigate to localhost/?verified=1 that the console screen of my browser would show this as the fullPath and verified as a query parameter. But all it shows is this:

```
{name: undefined, meta: {…}, path: '/', hash: '', query: {…}, …}
fullPath:"/"
hash:""
matched:(2) [{…}, {…}]
meta:{}
name:undefined
params:[[Prototype]]:Object
path:"/"
query:{}
```

Does anybody have any clue why Vue Router ignores the param in the URL? I have searched and tried endlessly but haven't found a solution.

Comment: can you try running that inside `router.onReady()`?

Comment: And when you see 'that' to which piece of code are you referring?

Comment: on where you do `console.log()` i.e `router.onReady(() => console.log(route.fullPath))`

Comment: Changed it to this:

beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {

            console.log('to', to);

            router.onReady(() => {
                console.log('onReady', this.$route.fullPath);
            });

            next();
        }
but that log-statement is never reached. At least it does not produce any output